# To compile a product listing, specifically a price, how can I use two tables to build a total price overall for product?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to produce a shopping site where I am selling items that fluctuate in price daily (precious metals). I have a table (products) that will contain a multiplier (something like "1.1") for each product. I basically don't want to have to go into my tables and change the prices of hundreds of items every day. My idea is to create another table where I will simply change the price field with the daily value each day. How can I make the final product price total the multiplier from one table multiplied by the entered daily price from another table. Or, is there a better way than using two tables? Here's the coding so far using just one table with a defined price :

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    //Connect To Mysql Database
    include"storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['id']);
    //Use This VAR To Check To See If This ID Exists, If Yes Then Get Product
    //Details, If No Then Exit Script and Give Message Why
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        //Get All The Product Details
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $category = $row["category"];
            $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y",strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        }

    } else {
        echo "That Item Does Not Exist";
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo "Data To Render This Page Is Missing";
    exit();
} 

mysql_close();
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: First, stop using mysql_query, look at mysli or PDO. That said, to simplify things you can just make your query do the math with something like `SELECT *, `product_price` * $product_multipler as `weighted_price` FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @j0k +1 Do you have that comment readily available, and you then just copy and paste it wherever you see such irresponsible behavioral? Good for you!

Comment: @JosephSilber I just grab it from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860140/569101 ;)

Comment: @j0k - Great! Keep up the good work. We need some policing around here :)

Comment: Suggested Title for This Post:  "How to apply time-sensitive values to a table of standing data".  Normally I would make this an edit, but it's a complete rewrite and I'd hate to get it wrong.  So I merely suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about a response that *isn't* the usual mysql_* related pedantry?

In the following schema I've broken the materials table away from the listed price so that they can be stored according to date. You might find this useful for records and/or invoicing.

```sql
TABLE products
  prod_id     INT PK
  prod_name   VARCHAR
  prod_price  DECIMAL
  mat_id      INT FK
  ...

TABLE materials
  mat_id    INT PK
  mat_name  VARCHAR
  ...

TABLE material_pricing
  mat_id            INT FK PK
  mat_price_date    DATE PK
  mat_price_factor  DECIMAL

SELECT
  p.prod_name,
  p.prod_price * pr.mat_price_factor AS 'cur_price'
FROM products p INNER JOIN materials m
  ON p.mat_id = m.mat_id
  INNER JOIN material_pricing pr
  ON m.mat_id = pr.mat_id
WHERE mat_price_date = TODAY()
```

I'm trying to think of a way to change the query to grab the last defined `material_pricing` entry for the relevant material, but I'm having a tough time lining up the data for a subquery...

**edit**: this should do the trick

```sql
SELECT
  p.prod_name,
  p.prod_price * pr.mat_price_factor AS 'cur_price'
FROM products p INNER JOIN materials m
  ON p.mat_id = m.mat_id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p1.*
    FROM material_pricing p1 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT mat_id, MAX(mat_price_date) 'mat_price_date'
      FROM material_pricing
      WHERE mat_price_date <= $target_date
      GROUP BY mat_id
    ) p2
    ON p1.mat_id = p2.mat_id
      AND p1.mat_price_date = p2.mat_price_date
  ) pr
  ON p.mat_id = pr.mat_id
```

Where `$target_date` in the innermost subquery would be replaced by either today's date, the `TODAY()` mySQL function, or the date of the invoice being displayed.

Comment: Perfect use for mysql_query!

Comment: @Smandoli more pedantry! `$target_date`, or `:target_date`, or `?`, or *whatever specific implementation you like*.

Comment: I can't claim to have reviewed your answer but I am upvoting because a schema change must be in order and therefore you are pointing in the right direction, and you are supplying explanation and support.  (Did you mean 'mere' pedantry?)